# How to get names of sales managers to show in Opportunity reports

Tags: salesforce, report, roles

In Salesforce, I have defined multiple roles of sales managers and their teams (Settings>Users>Roles).  How do I generate an Opportunities report that shows one column for opportunity owner (this is easy), and one column for the sales manager of the opportunity owner as defined in the roles (cannot seem to find this).

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom report type where you start with Opportunities and then "add fields via lookup" or something similar. Should let you do up to 5 "jumps": opportunity -> owner -> manager -> role.

Then build a new report that uses this report type.

Answer (score 0):

> No need to go with Custom report types.

Create a new report with standard report type of Opportunity object, Just add the column **'Opportunity Owner: Manager'** directly.

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsCE1.png)

You will get a column added with name of the manager of Opportunity's owner.